# Are there any alternatives to clipboard(www.clipboard.com). I was planning to use this to show clips of content embedded within my website

Tags: web-applications, web, clipping

Are there any alternatives or similar tools to [clipboard](http://techcrunch.com/2013/05/09/clipboard-acquired-by-salesforce-will-be-shuttered-on-june-30th/). I was planning to use this to clip & embed content from other sites and show them on my site with redirection on click on any link. But now they are being acquired by salesforce. I have explored several other tools including Bundlr, ScoopIt, Storify etc. But none of these seem to be able to embed the clipped content on a different website. Most of  these tools have an embed functionality with the clip summary that redirects to the original site instead of to the clipped content. 
Building such a tool is not an option right now for me, any suggestions would be helpful.